# Switching Position of two divs in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my page loads I have a `div` that is set to `display:block` and a second `div` that is set to `display:none`.

I've got a toggle switch that I would like to replace the shown div with the hidden div.

Currently, I'm trying to do this, but when I perform the switch I no longer have a reference to the `div` I've replaced and cannot toggle between them.

I can't position the Div's beside one another in the HTML as the page is a different Layout in Desktop so I'm wondering if it is possible to switch positions and hide the one being replaced?

This is my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/mdqmto9u/

I'd appreciate any help.

I tried cloning the divs before I switch them but that doesn't work either.

In my fiddle I'm trying to get it so that when you check the box the LEFT div switches position with the RIGHT div and vice versa

Comment: Couldn't you just [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) them? Incidentally please take the time to include your code in the question itself, don't rely on external sites.

Comment: I can't because it's a responsive layout and on my desktop version the divs are seperated by a central div. basically when I get below a certain screen width I hide the div on the far right.

Comment: do you want to do this only for a smaller screen?  if so use a CSS @media tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In my fiddle I'm trying to get it so that when you check the box the
>   LEFT div switches position with the RIGHT div and vice versa

Couldn't you just do this?

```
$('#check').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#div3').insertBefore($('#div2'));
        $('#div1').insertAfter($('#div2'));
    } else {
        $('#div3').insertAfter($('#div2'));
        $('#div1').insertBefore($('#div2'));
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z5u09uok/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, changing just the content.  If you want classes, etc. changed you could adjust your layout to apply css to the innerHTML of your divs.  Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/e9aa84ry/

```
$('#check').change(function(){
   var left = $('#div1').html();
   var right = $('#div3').html();
   $('#div1').html(right);
   $('#div3').html(left);
});
```